# Some successfull Skrill payment do not return to my website

Tags: php, payment, symfony-2.5

My website use Skrill payment. I realized that some of those payments return to my website so I can change the status of the booking, but others (almost 1000 over 9000) doesn't. Some of my clients need to repeat the process over and over until they get the process work. Others Skrill do the payment but my website do not get any response at all so to my website those payments are still pending. I constantly receive clients complains do to this Skrill bad behaviour.

The parameters I use to send to Skrill are the following:

```
<form action="{{ action_url }}" target="_self" id="skrillForm" style="display:none">
            <input type="hidden" name="pay_to_email" value="{{ pay_to_email }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="recipient_description" value="{{ recipient_description }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="transaction_id" value="{{ transaction_id }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="{{ return_url }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="return_url_text" value="{{ return_url_text }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="return_url_target" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="{{ cancel_url }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="cancel_url_target" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="status_url" value="{{ status_url }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="status_url2" value="{{ status_url2 }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="dynamic_descriptor" value="Descriptor">
            <input type="hidden" name="language" value="{{ language }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="confirmation_note" value="{{ confirmation_note }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="pay_from_email" value="{{ pay_from_email }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="logo_url" value="{{ logo_url }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="{{ first_name }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="lastname" value="{{ last_name }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="address" value="{{ address }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="postal_code" value="{{ postal_code }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="city" value="{{ city }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="country" value="{{ country }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{{ amount }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="{{ currency }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="detail1_description" value="{{ detail1_description }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="detail1_text" value="{{ detail1_text }}">
            {% if detail2_description is defined %}
                <input type="hidden" name="detail2_description" value="{{ detail2_description }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="detail2_text" value="{{ detail2_text }}">
            {% endif %}
            {% if detail3_description is defined %}
                <input type="hidden" name="detail3_description" value="{{ detail3_description }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="detail3_text" value="{{ detail3_text }}">
            {% endif %}
            {% if detail4_description is defined %}
                <input type="hidden" name="detail4_description" value="{{ detail4_description }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="detail4_text" value="{{ detail4_text }}">
            {% endif %}
            {% if detail5_description is defined %}
                <input type="hidden" name="detail5_description" value="{{ detail5_description }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="detail5_text" value="{{ detail5_text }}">
            {% endif %}
            <input type="hidden" name="payment_methods" value="{{ payment_methods }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="hide_login" value="1">
            <input type="submit" name="skrill_submit_button" id="submit_button" value="{{ button_text }}" >
        </form>
```

My website is in Symfony. I already read every Skrill documentation I found and I didn't find a proper answer to this issue. Can anybody help me, please? Best Regards

Comment: Unfortunately, there are little clues to help you. You mentioned your website does not get any response at all. Do you have any log files that may shed a light on your issue? This could be anything from an error in your website, an error in the remote server, a network problem, etc.

Comment: Please narrow down the scope of the question to what you believe is the core issue, present any errors you get. At the moment, there is no way to understand where the issue you are talking about may lie.